# How to increase insert speed using Bulk insert using AddRange and then SaveChanges in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have used Entity Framework to insert data into SQL tables.

For larger number of records, instead of `Add()`, I have used `AddRange()` and called `SaveChanges()` later.

It's still taking too much time to insert records - are there any solutions to increase the speed?

```
_Repository.InsertMultiple(deviceDataList);

await _Repository.SaveAsync();

public void InsertMultiple(List<string> deviceDataList)
{
    context.Devices.AddRange(devices);
}
```

Comment: Your code is too fragmented to get a coherent picture. `_Repository` vs `_deviceRepository`, `deviceDataList` vs `devices`. We need to see the entire process to be able to say anything sensible about it. Maybe creating `devices` is time-consuming, we can't tell. Also give an indication of the numbers of items you're dealing with.

Comment: i have updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you use Add in a foreach or AddRange, problem lies in SaveChanges method, as it stores changes in observed entities one by one I think. There are libraries out there that allows for real bulk insert of entities using under the hood mechanism of [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netcore-2.2)

Link to EF Core library: [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)

EDIT:
For EF6 I found this nuget: [EntityFramework6.BulkInsert](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.BulkInsert/) but I haven't personally used it so I can't say anything about it.

EDIT 2: I simplified this, using AddRange over Add will improve time of adding entities to change tracker, but still SaveChanges will could take very long time, so it's not a solution.

Comment: oh great anything more with code snippet useful will be helpful. thank you.

Comment: *It doesn't matter if you use Add in a foreach or AddRange* -- Quite the contrary, it may make a huge difference.

Comment: thanks can you add some sample code snippet it will be a great help

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, I know that it will make things faster, even a lot, but still SaveChanges is taking so long, that it still doesn't solve our situation. That was my simplification of this topic

Answer (score 8):

Using AddRange over Add is already a great improvement. It fixes the part that's slow in the Application.

However, the `SaveChanges` still take a lot of time because one database round-trip is made for every entity you save. So if you have 10k entities to insert, 10,000 database round-trip will be made which is **INSANELY** slow.

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is not free but allows you to perform all bulk operations including `BulkSaveChanges` and `BulkInsert`:

- Bulk SaveChanges
- Bulk Insert
- Bulk Delete
- Bulk Update
- Bulk Merge

Example

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Bulk Operations
context.BulkInsert(customers, options => {
   options => options.IncludeGraph = true;
});
context.BulkMerge(customers, options => {
   options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```

Comment: this is a good help thank you but looking for something that i can use with EF without any cost. may be i will use this for other product once approved :)